# $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ & $d_2(x,y)=|\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)|$ equivalent on $\mathbb R$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

We call two metrices equivalent if for all sequences $x_n,y_n\in\mathbb R$ it holds $\lim_{n\to\infty}d_1(x_n,y_n)=0 \iff\lim_{n\to\infty}d_2(x_n,y_n)=0$ .

I have given $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d_2(x,y)=|\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)|$ on $\mathbb R$and want to know if those two are equivalent.

So I can show
$$
0\leq d_2(x_n,y_n)\leq d_1(x_n,y_n)\rightarrow0
$$if $\lim_{n\to\infty}d_1(x_n,y_n)=0$.

How do you get the other way e.g. $d_1(x_n,y_n)\rightarrow0$ if $d_2(x_n,y_n)\to0$ ? Or aren't those metrices equivalent?

Comment: Try the sequences $x_n = n, y_n = n+1$.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks - they aren't equivalent!

Comment: Note that they induce the same topology on $\mathbb{R}$, but are very different metrics. With $d_1$, the space is complete, with $d_2$ it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They cannot be equivalent, since with $d_2$ we have that $\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded set, while with $d_1$ it is not. As suggested by copper hat, you may also notice that $(n+1)-n=1$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ while $\arctan(n+1)-\arctan(n)$ behaves like $\frac{1}{n^2}$ for large $n$s.